# Thread becomes null, even though it's initialized?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm having trouble with the some code from the Bluetooth Chat Service Sample. I'm able to connect to a HC-05 bluetooth device, but as soon as I call the write method from another activity I get a nullpointerexception because mConnectThread is Null. This is in activity A:

```
public void btn1(View view){

    byte[] n= {0x00000001};
    ChatService mChatservice = new ChatService();
    mChatservice.write(n);
}
```

This is the write method in my Chatservice class:

```
public  void write (byte[] out){    
    if(mConnectThread == null){
        Log.i(TAG, "mConnectedThread is null");
    }
    else {
        Log.i(TAG, "mConnectedThread is not null");
    }
}
```

I Initialized the mConnectedThread, similar to how its done in the bluetoothsample, in the connectthread which works fine.

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket
    // because mmSocket is final.
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;


    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        try
        {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Socket's create() method failed");
        }

        mmSocket = tmp;
    }


    public void run() {
        try {
            // Connect to the remote device through the socket. This call blocks
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception.
            mmSocket.connect();

        } catch (IOException connectException) {

            // Unable to connect; close the socket and return.
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {

            }
            return;
        }
            mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
            mConnectedThread.start();

    }
    // Closes the client socket and causes the thread to finish.
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

When I  call mConnectedThread in the write method it is Null. Why is mConnectedThread becoming Null even though it is initialized in Connectthread?

Comment: Is it `mConnectThread` or `mConnectedThread`?

Comment: You are swalling exceptions. Don't swallow exceptions and your problem may make itself apparent.

Comment: Show the declaration of attribute mConnectedThread.
How it's shared between the classes ConnectThread and Chatservice?

Comment: You have two classes ConnectedThread and ConnectThread, why?

Comment: My guess is the connection is failing, `connect` throws an exception but you aren't informed (cause you swallow the exception). `close()` then executes (and probably fails, no way to know, you swallowed the exception). Finally, you return, causing `mConnectedThread` to never be initialized. Use a debugger, don't swallow exceptions.

Comment: @eran connect thread establishes a connection to hc05 and connected thread manages the connection i.e. sending receiving data.

Comment: @eran @ aubin connect thread establishes a connection to hc05 and connected thread manages the connection i.e. sending receiving data. @ vince emigh the connection does work and does not throw exceptions. I did a nullcheck just after the initialisation in connectthread. At this point it is not null.

Comment: What kind of null check? `if(mConnectedThread == null) print("Is Null")`? Cause that wouldn't confirm anything. Did you use a debugger? You didn't give us enough code to run this, not even enough code to see all the relationships. The least you could do is include your own debugging attempts and results.

Comment: Sorry about that, i will post the full code. Yes it was the nullcheck like you wrote it.

Comment: So you're saying because the program never printed anything when null checking, that's how you know it's not null? How do you know it's not throwing exceptions? You dont do anything when an exception is thrown (`printStackTrace`), so you won't see anything in the console when you do get errors. Print the stack trace, bet you anything you're getting an exception.